# convert string object to list object in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string like `'banana'` and I'd to convert it into a list `['banana']`, in python.
I tried `''.join(list('banana'))` and other tricks, and I'm still back to square one! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Why not `[mystring]`?  It uses the list literal to create a list with just the value of `mystring` inside.

Comment: Thanks! I was just being too tired, I guess. Having being working for 8 straight hours. This is probably a proof that I should get some rest now.

Comment: Go to sleep bro.  Sleep deprivation never made you think clearer.  Just makes my name more ironic doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in a python shell:

```
>>> lst = ["banana"]
>>> type(lst)
<type 'list'>
```

Then, you can append some other fruits :

```
>>> lst.append('cherry')
>>> print "\n".join(lst)
banana
cherry
```